# Как узнать сколько внешней памяти записала программа?

Tags: c++, файлы, память

Как узнать сколько внешней памяти записала программа?

Например, программа создаёт 2 файла размером по мегабайту. Тогда результат должен быть 2мб.

Comment: За что минусют?

Comment: Не уверен, что какая-то ОС собирает такую статистику

Comment: @avp разве нельзя отслеживать системные вызовы?

Comment: Вообще-то,  можно. Сейчас не вспомню, как именно, но какой-то tool в *nix был. Запускаешь под ним программу и получаешь лог с вызовами и их аргументами. / Попробуйте задать такой вопрос, наверное кто-нибудь вспомнит и ответит, а вы потом распарсите лог и решите  этот свой вопрос

Comment: Делаете снимок файловой системы до и после, затем сравнивайте.

Comment: @user7860670 готовых инструментов нет?

Comment: @avp какой вопрос? Меня это и интересует в данном вопросе, хотя желательно решение не только для unix

Comment: @user7860670 и как определить что это именно моя программа сделала изменения? Сразу же много программ запущено

Comment: @chort, о, все же вспомнил -- [strace](https://losst.ru/komanda-strace-v-linux)

Comment: @avp я знаю про это, но надо же обрабатывать информацию: отслеживать определенные вызовы, если было удаление файла, то вычитать размер из результата и т.п.. Готовых инструментов для всего этого нет?

Comment: @chort, я про них не знаю (про strace-то еле вспомнил после вашего намека об отслеживании syscalls). Напишите свою программу, положите на githhub, вот и будет у всех такой инструмент -)

Comment: запускать изолировано

Comment: @user7860670 как это сделать? Система же работает, пишет файлы постоянно

Comment: любую песочницу возьмите, тот же докер